# Creating geological profile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, profile, geology

How can I create a profile like in the example in QGIS, that contains the geological layers?

I installed the plugins Profile tool and qprof, and I already got the profile, but without the layers.

[image: example]

Comment: maybe this plugin : https://gitlab.com/Oslandia/qgis/QGeoloGIS or this one : https://gitlab.com/Oslandia/albion

Comment: If your map has geological layers as depicted at the Earth surface then please note in this section that the ONLY unit that reaches the Earth's surface on the section is the top-most one. It is not clear how you would "create" a profile showing the underlying units from a map under these circumstances. You would need to incorporate some borehole data.